# Percentage in Lightning Components is not working correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, platform-bug, percent

It seems like Lightning isn't capable yet, to display percentage values intuitively.
I used many different ways to display the value with input and output formatted as percentage and all the components multiplied my default value "1" times 100 twice.

As [sfdcfox pointed out here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/144568/2513), Salesforce multiplies percentage fields automatically `*100`, before sending them to the frontend. This is a great feature! But it seems like unfortunately Lightning does the same thing again.

```
{!value}
<lightning:input           value="{!value}" type="number" formatter="percent" />
<ui:inputNumber            value="{!value}" format="##.00%" />
<ui:outputNumber           value="{!value}" format="##.00%" />
<lightning:formattedNumber value="{!value}" style="percent" />
```

results in this:

[image]

So Salesforce makes a percentage field with default "1" automatically a 100 when we query it, what worked totally fine with Visualforce and standard UIs, but Lightning Components seem not to be ready for this automation. So we need to divide every raw percentage value by code before displaying/modifying it and multiply it again when we save it to the database.

But this won't be possible for the lightning:input(**beta**) because it displays 10.000%, but when I click in it, it switches to 100, so there isn't even an easy way to handle this with data modification, we would need to modify it dynamically with events or something.

[image]

Comment: Just a clarification about your statement - "_we need to divide every raw percentage value by code before displaying/modifying it and multiply it again when we save it to the database._" -> If we enter 50 , we would divide it by 100 so that user sees 50 on UI, but when saving to database why do we need to multiply with 100 ? Salesforce would save it as .5 in database, correct?

Comment: @SfdcBat the way it goes back to the database is `Lightning UI -*> Lightning Controller -*> Apex -> Database`. And on both `-*>` arrows it will be devided by 100, so if you already devided it by 100 on init, you need to multiply it again. Else you will end up with 1%  instead of 100.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Spring'18 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_components.htm?edition=&impact=) reveal, that this will be fixed for lightning:input in the upcomming release:

> **lightning:input**
>
> *formatter*—The percent-fixed formatter is new for type="number". It displays your input value as is, for example, entering 10 results in
> 10%. Additionally, the percentage value is now rounded off to the last
> decimal point when the step value is provided. For example, when
> step="0.001" and a value of 0.12345 is provided with the percent
> formatter, you see 12.345% instead of 12% on blur. Similarly, when
> step="0.001" and a value of 12.3456 is provided with the percent-fixed
> formatter, you see 12.346%.

And I just verified that `formatter="percent-fixed"` fixed the issue for `lightning:input`.

Comment: In Summer'20 this is still a problem. I am using a lightning-datatable with one of the columns having the type percent and being editable. The field is displayed correctly, but once you start editing, non-intuitive things are happening. Very confusing for end-users.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this '％' instead.(Just copy this symbol '％' and past to your value).
Lightning won't see it as the normal '%'.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, when we get data in controller it is already divided by 100.
If you want to get real you need to multiply to 100.

Comment: Remove this answer as it's not helpful